# How to copy filtered rows from one spreadsheet to another, including formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to copy SOME rows from one spreadsheet to another, preserving all their formatting, Most importantly background color.

To extract the relevant rows the source data is passed through a filter. The script works fine, and the new sheet is populated with the correct data, but format is lost due to the filtering method.

How could I pass my range through a filter and keep the formatting on the rows that pass through the filter?

This is the relevant portion of my script:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();// source spreadsheet
  var ssh = ss.getSheetByName("main").getDataRange(); //source sheet, and range
  var data = ssh.getValues(); //source data
  var new_data = data.filter(function (row) {
    return row[0].startsWith("1") ; //copy if the first row starts with 1
  });
  var drg = new_s.getRange(new_s.getLastRow() + 1, 1,new_data.length,new_data[0].length ); // select range in destination sheet
  drg.setValues(new_data); // save filtered data in range at destination sheet
```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please set the destination Spreadsheet ID and destination sheet name.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var dstSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your destination Spreadsheet ID.
  var dstSheetName = "###"; // Please set your destination sheet name.

  var dstSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dstSpreadsheetId);
  var dstSheet = dstSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  var srcSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcSheet = srcSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("main");
  var temp1 = srcSheet.copyTo(srcSpreadsheet);
  var temp1Range = temp1.getDataRange();
  var { rows, heights } = temp1Range.getDisplayValues().reduce((o, [a], i) => {
    if (!a.startsWith("1")) {
      o.rows.push(i + 1);
    } else {
      o.heights.push(temp1.getRowHeight(i + 1));
    }
    return o;
  }, { rows: [], heights: [] });
  rows.reverse().forEach(e => temp1.deleteRow(e));
  temp1Range.copyTo(temp1Range, { contentsOnly: true });
  var temp2 = temp1.copyTo(dstSpreadsheet);
  var temp2Range = temp2.getDataRange();
  var dstRange = dstSheet.getRange("A1");
  temp2Range.copyTo(dstRange);
  temp2Range.copyTo(dstRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS, false);
  heights.forEach((h, i) => dstSheet.setRowHeightsForced(i + 1, 1, h));
  srcSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(temp1);
  dstSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(temp2);
}
```

- From your showing script, it supposes that the source sheet name is `main` and the source Spreadsheet is the active Spreadsheet. Please be careful about this.
- When this script is run, the fitered rows by `a.startsWith("1")` are copied from the source sheet in a source Spreadsheet to the destination sheet in a destination Spreadsheet by keeping the formats.

#### References:

- [copyTo(destination) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range))
- [copyTo(spreadsheet) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet))